# When does the fundamental theorem of calculus hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose I have a function $f$ such that
and I want to know when I can say we have: 
$$
F(M+1) - F(M)= \int_M^{M+1} F' (t) dt. 
$$

Suppose I know that $F$ is differentiable at every point in the interval $(M, M+1)$. Does the statement hold in this case?

Comment: In that case, how would the integral be defined?

Comment: Your question "What is the exact condition..." is rather unclear. One could simply answer it by saying "The exact condition for it to be true is that it is true".

Comment: Let me fix the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $F'(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[M,M+1]$ and $F$ is the antiderivative on $[M,M+1]$, then the statement you provided is true

$$\int_M^{M+1}F'(t)dt = F(M+1) - F(M)$$

If any point in the interval $[M,M+1]$ is a point of discontinuity, then you must compute what is known as a **type II improper integral** (there are two kinds of improper integrals, type I and type II). The definition of a type II improper integral involves limits. Any time you are integrating over finite interval in which every point in the interval is continuous, then we call that integral a "definite integral," and that is what you see above in the FTOC.

See below for a definition of a type I and type II improper integrals:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What if $F'(x)$ is continuous on $(M,M+1)$ but the limit of $F'(x)$  as $x$ goes to either of the end points is infinity? Does it still hold? I was wondering about this case...

Comment: In that case, no, the FTOC does not hold. If any point in the interval $[M,M+1]$ is a point of discontinuity, then you must compute what is known as a "type II improper integral" (there are two kinds of improper integrals, type I and type II). The definition of a type II improper integral involves limits. Any time you are integrating over finite interval in which every point in the interval is continuous, then we call that integral a "definite integral," and that is what you see above in the FTOC.

Comment: I just added definitions of type I and type II improper integrals, which is what you are looking for. I did not notice that your interval of integration was open initially.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check mark to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample:
$$f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x^2), x\ne 0;$$
$$f(0) = 0.$$
Is continuous in $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$. But $f'$ is unbounded near zero. See [A differentiable real function with unbounded derivative around zero](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiable-real-function-with-unbounded-derivative-around-zero/) for details.